# mysql to mongodb data migration plan high level

Tags: mysql, mongodb, migration, database

1) Get the current schema from the mysql database
2) Catalog the queries against that mysql database ranked by:
 a) usage/popularity/most important and b) current response time of the query
3) Create the data model using the above two items giving highest consideration to the most important queries

It'd be my first data migration from mysql to mongodb. Judge me! How does this plan look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Get the current schema from the mysql database

Forget that one... don't use a relational schema on something that is not relational. Forget normalisation and everything else. Just do what comes naturally. A good reading might by the [offical docs on schema design](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design)

> 2) Catalog the queries against that mysql database ranked by: a)
>   usage/popularity/most important and b) current response time of the
>   query
>   3) Create the data model using the above two items giving
>   highest consideration to the most important queries

Nothing that can be done 1:1 from *SQL to NoSQL. Just translate the queries into Mongo's Query Language. To get timings of the query, use the equivalent of ["EXPLAIN"](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain).